# Method for Debugging Userscripts in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I've attempted to make some modifications to a userscript to enable it to work under Chrome, but when I drag it into Chrome's window in order to install it, a dialog pops up and says 'Invalid Script Header'.

I've tried to use the Developer Tools, and built-in Javascript Console, to debug any errors occurring, but nothing appears to list any information.

`Console.app` does not list anything meaningful, except for the same error message I already know.

> [0x0-0x2d02d].com.google.Chrome: [346:1547:16686819618022:ERROR:extension_error_reporter.cc(55)] Extension error: Invalid script header.

How can I reasonably debug this error message and figure out what about the header is incorrect?

I'm using Chrome 15.0.861.0 on the dev channel, under OS 10.7 Lion.

Comment: I don't *think* there are any tools for this.  If you post the actual code here, someone may be able to spot the error.  Otherwise, you'd do it the old fashioned way: take a good script and the bad script and compare and half-split differences until the problem is determined.

Comment: post the code at http://gist.github.com/ please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally stumbled across the answer to this question, amusingly via a [Chromium Bug Report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68982).

As it turns out, the answer to my question was in the (significantly brief) [Userscript Documentation for Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) page.

> With Greasemonkey-style @include rules, it is not possible for Chrome to know for certain the domains a script will run on (because google.* can also run on google.evil.com). Because of this, Chrome just tells users that these scripts will run on all domains, which is sometimes scarier than necessary. With @match, Chrome will tell users the correct set of domains a user script will run on.

As it turns out, I had been using `@match http://*musicbrainz.org` in an attempt to match `www.musicbrainz.org` as well as `musicbrainz.org`, but per the quoted text, that doesn't save you from accidentally matching `evilmusicbrainz.org`. So, my solution was to use two lines:

```
@match http://*.musicbrainz.org
@match http://musicbrainz.org
```

Comment: This would explain the script running on extra pages, it does not explain the error message.

Comment: Chrome has very strong use and reuse of "same-origin" requests for security purposes. I could very well use `http://*/*` (and yes, I would have to specify `//*/*`), but if I specify a second level domain, it MUST be clean. You cannot glob in a second level domain. This means the TLD has to be clean too. Basically, you can blog a sub-domain, but if you do so it has to be delimited with a dot before specifying the second-level and TLD.

Comment: glob* a sub-domain

Answer (score 4):

Type:

```
 debugger;
```

Somewhere in the code, and the Web Inspector will pop up in that location. I have answered similar question here [Chrome debugger inject javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272365/chrome-debugger-inject-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out while I got the same error message ( **INVALID SCRIPT HEADER** ) that it accoured cause of a typo between the *// ==UserScript==* Header info.

wronge line

```
// @run-at document.end
```

corrected line

```
// @run-at document-end
```